# Responsive background glow

Tags: css

I need to create a section of a page that has the following background. It needs to be responsive so that regardless of the with or height of the div, the 'glow' areas remain roughly the same proportional size.

I have not idea where to start or what search terms I should be using. Any ideas how you would go about this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is this a picture or coded Background ?

Comment: Googling "css gradient" should get you there.

Comment: @Burak It's a picture

Comment: @jmargolisvt Thanks. I didn't even know where to start.

Comment: Have a look at this video from Kevin Powell (he's well worth a follow) whicih might give you some clues as he styles a shadow like the one you want under a button  https://youtu.be/6xNcXwC6ikQ

Comment: Play around with background-image (which lets you have several images) and radial-gradient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a snippet using two radial-gradient background images just to give you some ideas. Obviously you'll want to play around with the colors and dimensions to get exactly what you want.

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: radial-gradient(rgba(128, 0, 128, 0.5), transparent 10%), radial-gradient(rgba(128, 0, 128, 0.5), transparent 3%);
  background-color: black;
  background-size: 400% 200%;
  background-position: center -10vh, center -100vh;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<body></body>
```

Answer (score 0):

With a gradient. See aproximation

```
background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(115,4,101,1) 47%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%);
```

Comment: Thanks. The gradient isn't quite the same but at least I can start to research. The image about has two 'glow' spots rather than a vertical line.